# <asp:Content> does not correspond with <asp:ContentPlaceholder>

Tags: c#, asp.net

My ASP.NET page was not showing the controls. It just shows that master page error

> The page has one or more `<asp:content>` controls that do not correspond
>   with `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder` controls in the Master Page

Comment: List the exact error message.

Comment: Also show the PlaceHolder and Content parts form the apsx files

Answer (score 4):

Try setting

```xml
<title></title>
```

instead of

```
<title />
```

Comment: @jrummell I had a similar problem where I had the server title tag closed like 
`<title id="Title1" runat="server"/>`, this gave the same error as the OP post above hence the "suggestive" solution; worked once i changed it to: `<title id="Title1" runat="server"></title>`

Comment: Excellent! I had a script tag (on the master page) closed with /> and closing it normally with a </script> fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Remove comment (<%--    --%>) in the Master file, this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

All your `Content` controls have to reference existing `ContentPlaceHolders` on master page

For instance, if you have on your page

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" ID="Title" runat="server">
```

You must have something like this on your master page

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Header" runat="server" />
```

`ContentPlaceHolderID` is the property that must match against any `ContentPlaceHolder` ID on master page.

Comment: Yes also removing your commented section in the master page solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you must have a syntax error in the master.page's markup :

Ex)  %²>  in stead of  %>

If you validate your markup, I'm sure thar this will solve your problem

PI. I has the same error & it works for me ;)